# How to get third-party domains LocalStorage in Puppeter?

Tags: puppeteer, puphpeteer

I'm using the PHP wrapper `puphpeteer`, but at the end is the same.

I'm trying to get the `localSorage` variables that Youtube iframe drops on a specific site. However, when I try to get its `localStorage` by accessing it from its `contentWindow`, I get a cross-origin error:

```
Evaluation failed: DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.fundacionhortensiaherrero.org" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:46 {"userId":3,"exception":"[object] (Nesk\\Rialto\\Exceptions\\Node\\FatalException(code: 0): Evaluation failed: DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin \"https://www.fundacionhortensiaherrero.org\" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

The code:

```
$youtube_iframes = $this->page->querySelectorAll('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]');
foreach ($youtube_iframes as $iframe){
    $iframe->evaluate(JsFunction::createWithParameters(['el'])->body("el.setAttribute('src',el.getAttribute('src')+'&autoplay=1')"));
    sleep(2);
    Log::info($iframe->evaluate(JsFunction::createWithParameters(['el'])->body("return { ...el.contentWindow.localStorage }")));
}
```

If I `return { ...localStorage }`, I get the website's `localStorage`, but not the Youtube's one.

It must be possible to do so? At the end it's "my browser" and I should be able to access any domain's localStorage.

You can test it on this URL: https://www.fundacionhortensiaherrero.org/valencia-ya-disfruta-la-exposicion-manolo-valdes/

Answer (score 0):

## Suggested approach

You can build a 'running total' of `localStorage`, across all hosts that Puppeteer navigates.

This answer is based on Javascript, but you should be able to apply the same technique in `puphpeteer`...

## Code to get all localStorage

```
// Object to store all of the localStorage.
let runningLocalStorage = {}

// This will be called from within Puppeteer.
const updateRunningLocalStorage = (host, localStorage) => {
    runningLocalStorage[host] = localStorage
}

// Expose a Node.js function for the browser to call.
await page.exposeFunction("updateLocalStorage", updateRunningLocalStorage)

// Attach event to 'beforeunload', so that we can capture the localStorage before the browser navigates away.
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        updateRunningLocalStorage(window.location.host, window.localStorage)
    })
})

// Do the rest of your normal Puppeteer logic here...... 

// Finally get the final localStorage (because 'beforeunload' event won't get fired at the end)get fired at the end)
const finalLocalStorage = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return {
        host: window.location.host,
        localStorage: Object.assign({}, window.localStorage)
    }
})

updateRunningLocalStorage(finalLocalStorage.host, finalLocalStorage.localStorage)

// runningLocalStorage should now have all of our localStorage across all domains.
```